# Property of simultaneous Eigenform in analytic number theory

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I am self studying Tom M Apostol modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I have a doubt in proof of Theorem 6.14 in chapter modular forms with multiplicative coefficients whose image I am posting below.

> My doubt is how in 5th line of proof Apostol deduces that c(0) =0 .

Posting image [image]

Comment: He shows that $f(\tau) = c(0)$ is constant and the only constant modular form of weight $k \neq 0$ is $f = 0$.

Comment: @Paul K Thanks you very much